# proving a function is continuous for $ x =0$ and $x > 0$.

Tags: analysis, continuity

I have a function $f = 0$ if $x = 0$ and $f = \sin(x)$ if $x > 0$. I want to show that $f$ is continuous on $x \in [0, \infty)$. Here's my intuitive attempt: at $x =0$, $f(x)$ is a constant function, and thus continuous. Also, it is clear that $f(x) = \sin(x)$ is continuous in $x > 0$. Since $f(x)$ is continuous on $ x= 0$ and $ x \in (0, \infty)$, $f(x)$ is continuous in $[0, \infty)$. Is this approach correct?

Comment: No. You have to prove that $f(x) \to f(0)$ as $x \to 0$. If $f$ is continuous when restricted to $A$ and $B$ it need not be continuous when restricted to $A \cup B$.

Comment: The function $tan(x)$ is continuous from $[0,\pi/2)$ and $(\pi/2,\pi]$, Does that mean $tan(x)$ is continuous at $[0,\pi]$??